# Set NVMe drive as primary boot device in ASUS BIOS?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, nvme, asus

I just installed a NVMe drive on an adapter in my ASUS Sabertooth 990FX R2.0 based system. The BIOS is the latest version 2901 from 2016. The drive is a clone of my existing system.
The drive is recognize, bootable and seems to reach reasonable performance considering the config. The only problem is that the system will not boot directly on the drive no matter which setting I put in the BIOS.

I open the BIOS, set the drive as the first (and only) priority for storage drive.
When I reboot, the system tells me to insert a bootable drive.
I open the BIOS again and there, the storage drive is set to "PATA SM" which has no drive listed. The NVMe drive is listed below.
It is as if at boot time the system had not detected/initialize the drive yet and only does it after.

To boot the system, I am forced to open the BIOS and manually select the drive. How could I set the BIOS to make sure it boots using the NVMe drive? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by exploring the BIOS.
In the boot section there is an option to configure the compatibility with UEFI devices. Instead of leaving it on auto, I had to activate the highest level of compatibility and set legacy devices as priority (as opposed to UEFI priority).

Answer (score 1):

I do not have M.2 slot in my motherboard, used a PCIe Adapter Card to install the M.2 SSD. Bios did not detect but existing Windows 10 was able to detect it

I wanted to boot from the M.2 to get the system performance boosted, got lucky and was able to implement it and now I have windows running on M.2 SSD on a very old PC. got very good read/write speed

the idea is very simple, my old bios do not recognize the M.2 SSD so used a secondary Bios and installed Windows 10. every time I start the computer I now have two Bios one from the MB and one open source from a PenDrive

MB Bios -> PenDrive Bios -> M.2 SSD -> booting Windows 10

[Original Link]
https://www.hamishmb.com/booting-nvme-older-pc-refind/

[Lattest]
https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/

[PCI Adapter Card]
https://amzn.eu/d/dzDSLA4

MB: [Asus 990fx SaberTooth](https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/SABERTOOTH_990FX/HelpDesk_Knowledge/) (2012)